# How to setup Visual Studio 2013 for the use of Android support Library V7 to use Navigation drawer?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-support-library

I am a android xamarin newbie. I want a Navigation drawer in my android so I am trying to use Android support Library V7 AppCompact. But I am unable to setup the environment(probably as I am not being able to run the sample apps provided on GIT). So any help will be greatly approciated. Thank you.

Here are the projects I am trying to run which is provided here
http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/NavigationDrawer/

This is the error and warnings I am getting while compiling.

```
Warning    1   iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited   C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_drawer.png    NavigationDrawer
Warning 2   iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited   C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_drawer.png    NavigationDrawer
Warning 3   iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited   C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_drawer.png    NavigationDrawer
Warning 4   iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited   C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_drawer.png    NavigationDrawer
Error   5    error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 5   48  NavigationDrawer
Error   6    error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    public android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (android.view.ViewGroup p0, int p1)
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 28  47  NavigationDrawer
Error   7    error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    private native android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder n_onCreateViewHolder (android.view.ViewGroup p0, int p1);
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 33  55  NavigationDrawer
Error   8    error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    public void onBindViewHolder (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder p0, int p1)
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 36  70  NavigationDrawer
Error   9    error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    private native void n_onBindViewHolder (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder p0, int p1);
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 41  80  NavigationDrawer
Error   10   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder.java  5   48  NavigationDrawer
Error   11   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator does not exist
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_ItemAnimator_ItemAnimatorFinishedListenerImplementor.java  8   54  NavigationDrawer
Error   12   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor.java    8   41  NavigationDrawer
Error   13   error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView p0, android.view.MotionEvent p1)
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor.java    28  65  NavigationDrawer
Error   14   error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    private native boolean n_onInterceptTouchEvent (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView p0, android.view.MotionEvent p1);
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor.java    33  75  NavigationDrawer
Error   15   error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    public void onTouchEvent (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView p0, android.view.MotionEvent p1)
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor.java    36  53  NavigationDrawer
Error   16   error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    private native void n_onTouchEvent (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView p0, android.view.MotionEvent p1);
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_OnItemTouchListenerImplementor.java    41  63  NavigationDrawer
Error   17   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_OnScrollListenerImplementor.java   8   41  NavigationDrawer
Error   18   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
        android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.RecyclerListener
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_RecyclerListenerImplementor.java   8   41  NavigationDrawer
Error   19   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    public void onViewRecycled (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder p0)
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_RecyclerListenerImplementor.java   27  68  NavigationDrawer
Error   20   error: package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView does not exist
    private native void n_onViewRecycled (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder p0);
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView_RecyclerListenerImplementor.java   32  78  NavigationDrawer
Error   21   error: cannot find symbol
        if (getClass () == PlanetAdapter.class)
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class PlanetAdapter
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 23  7   NavigationDrawer
Error   22   error: method Activate in class TypeManager cannot be applied to given types;
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("NavigationDrawer.PlanetAdapter, NavigationDrawer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
  required: String,String,Object,Object[]
  found: String,String,PlanetAdapter,Object[]
  reason: actual argument PlanetAdapter cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter.java 24  28  NavigationDrawer
Error   23   error: cannot find symbol
        if (getClass () == PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder.class)
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder.java  20  7   NavigationDrawer
Error   24   error: method Activate in class TypeManager cannot be applied to given types;
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("NavigationDrawer.PlanetAdapter/ViewHolder, NavigationDrawer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "Android.Views.View, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065", this, new java.lang.Object[] { p0 });
  required: String,String,Object,Object[]
  found: String,String,PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder,Object[]
  reason: actual argument PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion
    C:\Users\superfast\Desktop\New folder\NavigationDrawer\obj\Debug\android\src\md5bcb996c917facdc1c00eade7083be557\PlanetAdapter_ViewHolder.java  21  28  NavigationDrawer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pull down this package and get it working with no changes. Did you restore the nuget packages?

Additionally, you may want to do a full clean and rebuild on the solution after restoring the packages.

I blogged about a newer way of implementing the navigation drawer using the design support library: https://blog.xamarin.com/add-beautiful-material-design-with-the-android-support-design-library/

I also have a GitHub repo full of Navigation drawer samples you may want to look at: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer

Comment: I have used your sample from github which was showing the same error as well but I have solved the problem.